# Convenient or convenience?

Tags: word-usage, usage

The following sentences is an example of how I get confused when writing English.

> 1. When will it be **convenient** for you to come over tomorrow?
> 2. When will it be **convenience** for you to come over tomorrow?

I seem to make this mistake often.  Is there any simply rule to follow that can help me straighten this problem?

Other words I use wrongly include owe-owed, relevant-relevance etc.

Answer (score 4):

"-ant" or "-ent" words are almost always adjectives. "-ance" or "-ence" are almost always nouns.

"When will it be convenient for you to come over?" uses "convenient" to describe "it", which is the situation or time. "When is a convenient time for you to come over?" means the same thing.

In the same way, "Is this relevant?" uses "relevant" to describe "this".

"Please call me at your convenience." uses "convenience" as a noun, there's nothing to describe. "Convenience" is the state of being convenient. One's convenience is when they find something easier to do.

Convenience can be used as an adjective in one place that I know of: A convenience store is a store that's trying to be convenient. A convenient store just happens to be convenient even if it isn't trying.

Answer (score 1):

1. should be:

convenient
"Would it be **convenient** for you to come over tomorrow?"

convenience
"Could you come over at your **convenience**"

A rule - **convenience** is generally used at the end of a sentence always with "at your".

You would never say "at your **convenient**". In the middle of a sentence - use **convenience** here.

Answer (score 0):

"Convenience store" came to my mind, too.  Grammatically, it is still regarded as a noun in this place, even though it has the function of an adjective here.  There are many noun compounds (or compound nouns) where the first noun describes the range or kind of the one that follows it: fire engine, alarm clock, five-dollar note.  I agree that in the case of "convenience store", there's no logical reason why the noun was chosen rather than the special adjective form.  I suppose the focus is on the sense of freedom that the customer gets, rather than on the store itself.